# Scroll infinito para celular

Tags: rolamento

Fiz um *scroll* infinito e funcionou perfeitamente, porém quando fui testar em um celular ele simplesmente não funcionou, o método que usei foi esse:

```
win.scroll(function() 
    {
        if($(document).height() - win.height() == win.scrollTop()) 
        {
        }
});
```

Comment: Dando uma breve olhada na função: se `$(document).height() - win.height()` for igual a `win.scrollTop()`, então não faz nada, pois o conteúdo do bloco `if` está vazio. Você mesmo escreveu ou pegou o trecho de algum lugar?

Comment: No caso, dentro do IF eu gero o novo conteúdo, o problema é mesmo na parte do scroll, por que em desktop funciona.